# Is this a typo in Ihara's "On discrete subgroups of the two by two projective linear group over p-adic fields"?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, algebraic-groups

In Eq. (9'') on p. 227 of Ihara's paper *"On discrete subgroups of the two by two projective linear group over p-adic fields"* ([link](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1260541107)), where the second line says $$"\log Z_{\Gamma}(0,\chi)=1",$$ is this maybe a typo and he should have 0 instead of 1? Why does he even need to do two separate cases anyway?

Comment: Well, indeed if the right-hand side were $0$, then there *wouldn't* be a need for two cases; so maybe it's intentional?

Comment: After all I guess it's just an accident, as you suppose; Theorem 2 on p. 227 clearly gives $Z_\Gamma(0, \chi) = 1$.  I have no idea why Ihara separates the two cases.